# Definition of star operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As picture below, why the star operator have different form on tangent and cotangent (3.3.4 and 3.3.8) ?   Besides, why need Riemannian structure for definit star operator on cotangent ?

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part about vector spaces you have copied sounds misleading as it stands. To define a $*$-operation on a vector space, you need an inner product and an orientation. The rule for computing $*(e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_p})$ only applies to the elements in an orthonormal basis of $V$. (Otherwise the operation would not be well defined.)

This also explains why (3.3.8) looks different from (3.3.4). The one-forms $dx^i$ usually are not orthonormal (and cannot be chosen to be orthonormal). Computing the $*$-operator in this basis is tedious in general, but for $*(1)$ it is OK: Given an orthonormal basis $e_i$, $dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$ is the volume spanned by the vectors $dx^i$ times $e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n$, and this leads to (3.3.8).

Comment: So, what is the exact definition of star operator on $\wedge^p(T^*_xM)$ ? It is likely to the situation of tangent space that if $dx^i$ is orthonormal , the definition is likely 3.3.3 ?

Comment: You can use the definition of 3.3.3 in terms of a local orthonormal coframe and then compute how things change if you go to a general frame (but this gets a bit tedious).